# How to copy alternate images from one folder to another in python

Tags: python

I want to implement a python code which would select a 1 image after 3 images and so on till the last image in an sequential manner in the specified folder  and copy those images to another folder.

Example : As shown in the screenshot

link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPdOd.png

Comment: Yes but that is not necessary ! It should copy in a sequential manner i.e i mean in horizontal manner from 1st image  and so on to the last image.

Comment: Are you trying to copy every alternate Image or images named in multiple of 4?

Comment: It is irrelevant to the naming ! I just want to copy 1 image skipping 3 images and so on in a given folder of images

Comment: The issue is os.listdir() the function that you need doesn't maintain order, so if that is not necessary, it can be done easily

Comment: I mean the order is necessary i.e copying images in  a sequential manner and not in any random order.

Comment: Then there names have to denote that sequence, or their date modified or something has to, i.e. for the code to follow some sequence, it has to be explicitly explained what should the sequence be based on.

Comment: I would say that the sequence is based on the naming.

Comment: @SharangBanavali you need alphanumeric sorting? `sorted(os.listdir())` returns what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is same but I think it is more clear for all

```
import os
import shutil

path_to_your_files = 'your pics path'
copy_to_path = 'destination for your copy'

files_list = sorted(os.listdir(path_to_your_files))
orders = range(1, len(files_list) , 4)

for order in orders:
    files = files_list[order] # getting 1 image after 3 images
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(path_to_your_files, files), os.path.join(copy_to_path, files))  # copying images to destination folder
```

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('YOUR PICS DIRECTORY HERE')
every_4th_files=[f for idx,f in  zip(range(len(files)), files) if not idx%4]
```

Is it what you need?

## Edit

To copy images I recommend to use `shutil.copyfile`.

If you encounter a problem - inform about it.

Comment: How do i specify the target directory to which the images should be copied? I am new to python

Comment: `Os.listdir()` randomizes how files are loaded, is not sorted or the order in which files are shown in the directory, won't work.

Comment: `sorted(os.listdir(...))` for rescue.

Comment: @anand_v.singh you're not exactly correct - `os.listdir` does not randomizes output it does not **garantee** order of output

Comment: @AlexYu Fair Point, still brings possibility unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile
files = sorted(os.listdir('Source Folder'))
4thFile = [fileName for index, file in zip(range(len(files)),files) if not index%4]
for file in 4thFile:
    copyfile(os.path.join(src_path, f), os.path.join(dest_path, file))
```

That should get the job done.

Comment: I suppose smth like `shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(src_path, f), os.path.join(dest_path, file))` will be a complete solution.

Comment: @AlexYu a little too much spoon feeding, but edited accordingly 

Comment: My thoughts exactly!

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Idk which syntax is wrong in 4thFile = [fileName for index, file in zip(range(len(files)),files) if not index%4]